# call cakephp plugin controller actions from outside of plugin (within base application)

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-1.3

is it possible to call a controller action of a plugin outside of that plugin (in the base application), for example, let's say I have a plugin called `test` in `app/plugins` and inside that plugin I have a controller called `users` in `app/plugins/test/controllers/users_controller.php`. Is it possible to call, let's say the `add` action of the `users_controller` of my plugin in one of the controllers of the base application (the application that the plugin is a part of)?

Please let me know if this is possible and how to achieve this

Comment: is there any new update for this question? is this possible in cakephp 3?

Answer (score 0):

You could move that logic to a Component then include in `var $components` array in any controller that needs to use that logic.

If the logic is purely just adding, you can move it to the model and then include that model into the controller that needs to use it using `Controller->loadModel('Plugin.Model'); Model->add();`

It would help if you could provide more info on what exactly the add method does and why you need it called from other controllers.